# Set up base URL in Bitbucket and configure Hosting in Plesk

Tags: plesk, bitbucket-server

I successfully installed Bitbucket on my Server and now I'm trying to get the base-URL to work.

As a Server Administration Tool I'm using *Plesk Onyx Version 17.0.17* - There is only one IP-Adress linking to my Server but multiple websites (different URL's) organized in Plesk under the Domain-Panel.

When I create the desired url in Plesk an try to use it in Bitbucket as base-URL - it doesn't work. It always fallsback to the IP literal and the default bitbucket Port 7990.

When I create the desired url in Plesk an try to use it in Bitbucket as base-URL **with the appending Port** - it works (but with every URL that is on my Server) and the port is present in every URL.

### How can I specify one single URL exclusively for Bitbucket and use it as Base URL without the appending port number ":7990"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tutorial from Atlassian - didn't find it at first because I only searched in the Bitbucket Documentation but with this Tutorial it worked for me!

https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html